# How to keep clicking 'Read More' button until there is no longer any content to display using Nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I am using Nightwatch for my app. I'm currently testing to make sure everything works well even if the "Read More" button is clicked until all content is fully loaded via ajax. How can I make Nightwatch keep clicking the "Read More" button until there's no more content to load/it can't scroll down any more?

This is what I currently have:

```
browser
    .url(page)
    .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)

    .execute('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);') // scroll to bottom
    .click('.read-more a')

    .pause(10000)
    .end();
```

The above code will scroll to the bottom and click the "Read More" button once. How can I make it so it'll keep going until there's no more content to load and can't scroll any further?

Comment: Do you know how many times the button will be clicked?

Comment: No, the length can change as more content is added.

Comment: There are many reasons why this might not be something you want to do.
Imagine the following realistic scenarios.

1. The "Read More" button is broken and doesn't do anything, your test will hang forever  

2. There is no response from the server after clicking "Read More" and nothing is returned, your test will hang forever  

3. There is a test flaw and the button is not clicked, your test will hang forever.
  
Usually with pagination testing it's enough to load one page.
Also, do you plan to assert something after clicking Read More?

Answer (score 0):

Execute your code (execute and click) in a infinite loop and break it when browser.elementNotPresent(".read-more a")